# Error when runnung nvme test cases

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, qemu, pci-e, solid-state-drive

Recently I have installed QEMU virtual machine on my ubuntu host machine and build dnvme (the nvme driver) and tnvme on it.I was trying to execute tnvme on simulated nvme hardware.I am getting a error "Unable to extract driver version information and  Unable to build the test foundation  when give command like ./tnvme -s to summarize test supported.I am not able to run any test cases in QEMU.

So, how can I get more debug information on this error? Or, how can I solve this issue and how can i run at least one tnvme test case on QEMU.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this myself. It may be that you haven't disabled the kernel nvme driver and enabled dnvme instead as required.

The following steps worked for me to resolve the issue (ran with root privileges):

1. Discover running nvme drivers by calling `lsmod | grep nvme`
2. Kill any nvme driver that appeared there using `rmmod` (e.g `rmmod nvme`)
3. Navigate to the root folder of your download of dnvme and run `insmod dnvme.ko` in order to start the dnvme driver.

You can verify the driver is now running by checking `lsmod | grep nvme` and seeing that the only output is dnvme. Then try running tnvme again.

This needs to be done after every system boot before running tnvme.

Source: https://github.com/nvmecompliance/tnvme/issues/35 (contains further suggestions that may work for you).